# css for all screen size

Tags: css, resize

I want to have two input with one button for user to enter their username and password, and
I'm using this css code for controlling the input tag in my website in order to appear it properly on all screen size, and it works fine.

```
.controller {
 width: 98%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 7px 5px 4px;
 color: #555;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-family: inherit;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
    }
```

I want to have some dynamic text which is retrieved from the database below these two inputs for the user. Now my problem is that if the text is long it will not appear properly below the inputs and affects them to not fit the screen, as long as the text is only 5 to 10 words there is no problem.

here is the html file for the inputs

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="answer">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        Login Name:<input type="text" name="id" class="controller"></input>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Password:<input type="password" name="pass" class="controller"></input>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="submit" value="Login"></input>
                    </li>
                </ul>
    </form>     
</body>
```

and here is the CSS code

```
 .controller {
 width: 98%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 7px 5px 4px;
 color: #400;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-family: inherit;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
    }
```

please can anyone advice me what I have to do or give a css code for controlling the problem.

thank you very much for any answer and sorry for my long question.

Comment: is the  text in a separate container from the `.controller` class and positioned with the css?

Comment: Yes I'm looking to have a separate container for the text, and I have used     style="word-wrap: break-word"    it works for the text, but it affects the inputs and they not appeared fit to the screen.

Comment: It is difficult to know exactly what is going on without more code. But if I were to take a guess, you need to wrap the text in an appropriate `<p>`, or if the page is more complex than inside of a `<div>`. Then you just need to position the text and define a width that you like.

Comment: Dear Dave Thank you very much for your clarification, can you please advice me how positioning the text in order to appear properly on all screen size, if you can give me a sample code or example.

Comment: I will gladly do that if you posted you're html and css so I could see what was going on. Use http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I have edited the question and added the html and css code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I think that this is what you want to do. After your form,

```
<div id="response">
    <p> Some Long Block Of Text That Will Wrap Around This Div </p>
</div>
```

then, in the CSS you get something like this going on:

```
#response
{
    width: 75px; /*desired width*/
    margin-top: 25px; /*distance from the form above*/
}
#response p
{
    /*anything you want to do to that specific <p> */
}
```

​I'm not sure how you are getting the dynamic text, but I'm guessing that it is a script that is getting info from `answer` and putting it in the html. Just place that info inside of the `<p>` that's in `#response`